# Unable to delete shared contacts

Tags: google-api-client, google-people-api

I am able to list the shared contacts in the python API using the `listDirectoryPeople` method (with the DirectorySourceType `DIRECTORY_SOURCE_TYPE_DOMAIN_CONTACT`) in the People API.

However, when I try to delete a specific shared contact (by `resourceName`) using the `deleteContact` method, I get the error:

```
"Resource name "people/<resource_string>" is not a valid contact person resource."
```

I am authenticating my script with a SuperAdmin and using the scopes:

```
SCOPES = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/directory.readonly'
]
```

Why am I unable to delete shared contacts?

Answer (score 1):

As the scope name `directory.readonly` suggests, it is read-only, and you can't modify/delete these contacts using this scope in the People API.

In order for Google workspace admins to edit these contacts you need a different API, check out the `Shared Contacts API`: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/domain-shared-contacts

Comment: The shared contact API no longer works.  When I try to use it, I get an error saying to use the People API.

Comment: When using the shared contacts API:  

`Server responded with: 400, Contacts API is being deprecated. Migrate to People API to retain programmatic access to Google Contacts. See https://developers.google.com/people/contacts-api-migration.`

Comment: oh, that's interesting... i'm not seeing any official scope for editing directly contacts in the People API docs, you might want to file an issue at: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=344199&template=1041029

Comment: Most likely you are actually requesting from the contacts API. The domain shared contacts API and normal Contacts API share the same URL format, the difference is whether you are requesting contacts from a domain or a user. Example domain URL is "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/example.com/full". Example user URL is "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/user@example.com/full".

Domain shared contacts API works fine for me.